# Moongose model type is not defined when importing to test file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

i have a problem with exporting moongose model to jest test files

That is my model

```
import mongoose, {Schema} from 'mongoose';

export interface IReaction extends mongoose.Document {
    reactionType: string;
    parentId: string;
    userId: string;
    onModel: string;
}

export interface IAddReaction{
    reactionType: string;
    parentId: string;
    onModel: string;
}
export const reactionTypes = ['LIKE', 'DISLIKE', 'HAHA', 'ANGRY', 'SMILE']

export const reactionSchema : Schema = new Schema(
    {
        reactionType: {type: String, required: true},
        parentId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, refPath:'onModel', required:true},
        userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'User', required: true},
        onModel: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            enum: ['Post', 'Comment', 'SubComment']
        }
    },
    { timestamps: true }
)

export default mongoose.model<IReaction>("Reaction", reactionSchema);
```

and that's my test file

```
import * as dbHandler from '../../dbHandler'
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Reaction, {reactionTypes} from "../../../models/Reaction";


describe('reactionManager test',(() => {
    beforeAll(async () => await dbHandler.connect());
    afterEach(async () => await dbHandler.clearDatabase());
    afterAll(async () => await dbHandler.closeDatabase());

    it('should create new reaction', async () => {
        const parentId = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId();
        const userId = new mongoose.mongo.ObjectId();
        const reaction = new Reaction({
            reactionType: reactionTypes[0], // LIKE
            parentId,
            userId,
            onModel: "Post",
        });

        const savedReaction: any = await reaction.save();

        expect(savedReaction._id).toBeDefined();
        expect(savedReaction.parentId).toBe(parentId);
        expect(savedReaction.onModel).toBe("Post");
        expect(savedReaction.reactionType).toBe(reactionTypes[0]);
    })
}))
```

Whenever i want to import my moongose model to test file i get an error

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRu0R.png)

When i remove IReaction from mongoose.model then working perfectly fine but i am losing insight on all attributes in my interface.

```
export default mongoose.model<IReaction>("Reaction", reactionSchema); <-- HERE IS THE PROBLEM
```

In other files which are not test file there is no problem.

Comment: This an issue with your setup rather than your code.  Make sure that all of your packages are up to date.  Are there any other files in your project that have typescript generics in them?  Do they work in your tests?

Comment: @LindaPaiste yes there was a problem with my Jest config. I am using typescript so i switched up to ts-jest instead and now its working perfectly fine. Thank you for help